# Convert Sketch file to Layered editable PSD

Tags: adobe-photoshop, conversion, imagemagick, user-interface, psd

I'm trying as hard as I can to convert a Sketch file to a layered and editable PSD file. I know I'm not the only one to have asked this question and this is currently a big challenge that lot of people are trying to solve, including the folks at Avocode.
Personnally, I don't ever use Photoshop for UI design. But I was just in a project where they absolutely need my files in psd and can't take "no" for an answer.
Here's what I've tried so far:

- Paste Sketch artboard into Affinity Designer, export in psd. The text layers
  are flattened.
- Export SVG/PDF/EPS from Sketch, open in Illustrator, export in PSD.
  The text layers are flattened again.
- I also tried to open my files in https://www.photopea.com/, but my
  files are too heavy.
- Export SVG from Sketch, tried to convert SVG to PSD via ImageMagick, and it flattens the whole svg to a single layer.
- I took a close look at the options offered by Avocode, but they don't have a working option for what I'm trying to achieve.

So if anyone has another idea (that doesn't include redesigning all the files) I'd be very very happy! And lots of other designers too, I'm guessing. I don't need a perfect psd file, but I do need the distances between elements to be respected, and to be able to edit the text layers directly in the psd file.

So who wants to brainstorm?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Zoé

Comment: Hi, what was the problem with Photopea? Have you tried to disable WebGL (More - Use WebGL) ?

Comment: Hi Ivan, the problem with Photopea is that it couldn't open my files since they're too heavy. 
But I've just tried to open lighter files, and it seems to work almost perfectly! The only problem I've seen so far is that the vector masks are randomly modified and the symbol overrides are not always respected.
Still, for my needs, it's almost too good to be true!
Thanks for your reactivity!

Comment: A Graphic Design (Stack Exchange) answer on this [topic](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12930/how-do-i-import-a-vector-illustration-into-photoshop)